# why loop inside recursive function not complete in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, recursion, tree

I need to :
check every node in tree start from the root, loop on its node ,check each node if there any child related to that node and call the same function again (recursive function).
My code is:

---

```
var tree = new Array();

tree[0] = ["Node1", "Node2", "Node3", "Node4"] 
tree[1] = ["Node1", "Node2"] 
tree[2] = ["Node1", "Node2", "Node4"] 


function schTree(treeArr){
 //LOOP ON CHILD NODE TO CHECK IF THE NODE IS PARANT FOR SOME OTHER NODE OR NOT and do some actions 
     for(i=0;i<treeArr.length; i++){

                if(treeArr[i].length){
                     schTree(treeArr[i]);
                  };
      }
  }

//call search tree function 
schTree(tree);
```

---

The problem is :
The loop did not complete if I recall the function.

I think that each calling for the function recursively It construct new function above the current function (work on the same place in memory not creating new function)

How to : 
Make normal recursive function ?????

Thanks in advance

Maged Rawash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only received the first node because you declared your for loop without the keyword `var`

`for(i=0;i<treeArr.length; i++)`
By the time the first nodes array was traversed, i was equal to 3

Here are my comments on the rest of your code

```
var tree = [];
tree[0] = ["Node1", "Node2", "Node3", "Node4"] 
tree[1] = ["Node5", "Node6"] 
tree[2] = ["Node7", "Node8", "Node9"] 

//recursive function that checks if a node 
function schTree(treeArr){

    //FIX A
    //find out if element is an array
    if(Array.isArray(treeArr)){

    //FIX B
    //You did not declare i with var, meaning each recursive call
    //carried the prior value of i with it.
    //so after iterating over the first node, i = 3
    //which is greater than the length of node 1 and 2
     for(var i=0;i<treeArr.length; i++){

            //FIX C
            //removed inner length check, not needed
            //schTree checks for array before getting to this
            //point
             schTree(treeArr[i]);
      }
    }
    else {
        //While you'd probably want to do a clause for
        //objects, we'll assume only arrays here.

        //FIX D
        //Do something with the non array element
        console.log(treeArr);
    }
  }
  schTree(tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're checking it isn't going to work because letters have a `.length` of `1`, so you're going to get pass in `tree`, `tree[0]`, `tree[0][0]`, and then infinitely pass in `tree[0][0][0]` until the stack gets too big and you get a `RangeError`. Instead, do this:

```
function schTree(treeArr){
    for (var i = 0; i < treeArr.length; i++){
        if (treeArr[i].constructor === String && treeArr[i].length > 1) schTree(treeArr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I consider the string like parant and each letter is leave no problem  with that ..

Comment: OK, but you need to make sure that the string has a length greater than `1` so you don't loop on a letter.